# Maximum index size for array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

The following code is crashing my program.  I found the problem is the size of the array.  If I reduce the size to 320*320, it works fine.  Does it make sense that this wound be a limitation?  If so, what is a work around?  I am coding in Objective C for IPhone.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
 int life_matrix[320*350];
 x_size=320;
 y_size=350;
 for (int counter=0; counter < x_size; counter++)
 {
  for (int counter2=0;counter2 < (y_size); counter2++)
  {
   life_matrix[counter*(int)x_size+counter2] = rand()%2;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[leiz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549968/maximum-index-size-for-array/1549971#1549971) advice is correct, you really should be allocating this dynamically otherwise you run the risk of running into a situation were the size of the array is larger than the available memory on the stack.

Also the formula you are using to map a 2-dimensional grid to a 1-dimensional array is incorrect. You should be multiplying by y_size instead of x_size.

```
life_matrix[counter*(int)y_size+counter2] = rand()%2;
```

or you could flip your counters

```
life_matrix[counter2*(int)x_size+counter] = rand()%2;
```

Another approach to solving this would be to use it as a 1-dimensional array for initialization:

```
for(int n = 0; n < x_size * y_size; ++n) {
    life_matrix[n] = rand()%2;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The array is allocated on stack and usually the stack size is limited. If you need a big array, usually it is a good idea to allocate it on heap.

Comment: Thanks, I think this can be done in C++ with the 'new' constructor.  But do you know how to do this in Objective C?

Comment: You could use old C malloc, or use std::vector I presume. Sorry I don't know Objective C very well.

Comment: you can use malloc/free in Objective-C for dynamic memory management.